# Track downloads of image using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an image at www.mydomain.com/images/cute_cat.png and I would like to put some javascript code to see whenever someone makes a request to the page using google analytics javascript snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: If you have a download link you could potentially to the tracking in the onclick before (returning true) and letting the browser continue on to the link.

Comment: The purpose is to track whenever the image is embedded somewhere where I am not aware of it...

Comment: GA tracks page views and events, it's not really intended for low-level logging like that.  You should be using something like Aw-stats or Urchin.

Comment: Using JS is not the solution you are looking for. Just check your server's access logs and see who is embedding your images.

Comment: You can also try redirecting requests coming from other websites to a server side script that "pings" Google Analytics with the data you want encoded in the URL and then redirect the request to the actual image. If you're using PHP take a look at this http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some more details on my second suggestion.

In your htaccess add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)cute_cat\.png $  trackthis.php?campain=cutecat [L]
```

and in trackthis.php use the API I suggested above to send your data to Google.
Then just use a header call in PHP and redirect to the image.